# How to get selfinjective algebras the smallest class of algebras having the following properties?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over a field K. $A$ is called a selfinjective algebra if it is injective as an $A$-module; $A$ is called a Frobenius algebra if $A \cong D(A)$ as left (or right)$A$-module. In the book "Frobenius algebra I" by K.Yamagata, we know every Frobenius algebra is a selfinjective algebra and selfinjective algebras are closed under Morita equivalences.

But it says on page 352 " the class of all finite dimensional selfinjective K-algebras is the smallest class of finite dimensional K-algebras which contains the class of all Frobenius K-algebras and is closed under the Morita equivalences". Who can tell me why selfinjective K-algebras is the smallest class having that two properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already wrote, Frobenius $K$-algebras are selfinjective and being selfinjective is closed under Morita equivalence. Thus, the closure of Frobenius $K$-algebras under Morita equivalence is contained in the class of selfinjective algebras.

For the converse, take a selfinjective algebra. Then, it has a basic version. This basic version is a Frobenius algebra, see e.g. these notes by Farnsteiner:  https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~sek/select/rf2.pdf. The claim follows.

Comment: Yes, I know that a basic selfinjective algebra is a Frobenius algebra. But then how to get the claim? Is there any special meaning of basic algebras?

Comment: The basic version is always Morita equivalent. So every selfinjective algebra is Morita equivalent to a Frobenius algebra, hence in the closure under Morita equivalence of Frobenius algebras.